# Error in Selenium webDriver Junit Test?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am getting following error in my script

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbrZ5.png]

does that mean i am missing any jar file which i need to include in liabrary or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to include the jmeter library in your project.

Comment: yeah i figured out.That error is gone but now getting error with following import org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager;
import org.apache.log.Logger;

Answer (score 1):

Include all jars from the following JMeter folders:

- /lib
- /lib/ext

into your project classpath as well as Selenium libraries.

By the way, are you aware of existing [WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which integrates JMeter and Selenium so you won't have to recompile your JUnit code in case of any changes on Selenium side of things.